# How do I fix this for an s3 bucket in aws

Tags: json, amazon-s3

{
"Id": "Policy1689344461274",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Stmt1689344457259",
"Action": [
"s3:GetObject"
],
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pwmawsbucket/*",
"Principal": "*"
}
}

API error on this

a AWS Policy Get-object policy file , used the generator,

Answer (score 1):

The Principal field identifies the principal that is allowed or denied access to a resource. You need to specify an IAM user, federated user, IAM role, or AWS account that you want to allow or deny access to the S3 bucket.

The resource only specifies the bucket but not the objects in the bucket. For s3:GetObject, you would usually specify the bucket and any objects in the bucket as well. To specify all objects, you could use "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pwmawsbucket/*".

Answer (score 0):

Resource should be `arn:aws:s3:::pwmawsbucket/*` (notice the `*` at the end)